# How to install DraftSight on Ubuntu 64bits?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I downloaded the deb file to install DraftSight but trying to install the package using dpkg failed with the following error:

```
The installation or removal of a software package failed.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 196655 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../Downloads/draftSight.deb ...
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/ShowLicense: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
dpkg: error processing archive /home/helios/Downloads/draftSight.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

What missing packages do I need to install to properly run DraftSight?

Comment: Are you running 14.04 64bits? how did you try to install the deb file (the command is missing)

Comment: yes, i'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit and i set up draftsight the deb file. Help me please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To easily install and run DraftSight CAD in 64 bit Ubuntu you need to install several i386 packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libuuid1:i386 libice6:i386 libsm6:i386 libxt6:i386 libaudio2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
```

Then just open the dash to start the application:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what more applycations to draw CAD? I'm student, I need app to substitute autoCAD.

Comment: There's a complete list available in the Ubuntu (French) forum: http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/mecanique

Answer (score 2):

This is tested on my pc (Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits):
Install  package **libgtk2.0-0:i386**  then Draftsight will install ok.

Comment: Thank you but this not installed :( Not erro but can't installed.

Answer (score 0):

To install DraftSight on 14.04 (64 bits):

Step 1: Install i386 libraries (even mentioned in @sylvain answer)

```
sudo apt-get install libuuid1:i386 libice6:i386 libsm6:i386 libxt6:i386 libaudio2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
```

Step 2: Download DraftSight Installer :

[download **.deb** from source](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/)

Step 3: Install DraftSight CAD

after changed to downloaded folder run

```
sudo dpkg -i draftSight.deb
```